# Why does this RewriteRule work for all extensions but .php?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

This simple RewriteRule that I am using for practicing with .htaccess files works almost always:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ test.html
```

When I have the file `flowers.html` and I use http://localhost/flowers I get redirected to `test.html`, however when I rename `flowers.html` to `flowers.php` I get a 404 page with the message `The requested URL /flowers was not found on this server`. Does anyone know what causes this?

**EDIT:**
When I create an empty file called `flowers` it does redirect properly to `test.html`. What is going on here?

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Try setting `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your file. Which version of Apache? What OS? Note that the directive above is a "rewrite", not strictly a "redirect" - presumably you are not seeing a URL change in the browser's address bar?

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you very much, if you could add this as an answer Ill accept it. Adding `Options -MultiViews` fixed it. Are there any consequences to adding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does sound like a conflict with `MultiViews`, so try adding the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to disable `MultiViews`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

MultiViews is not enabled by default, so maybe this has been enabled in your server config?

When MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) is enabled, a request for `/flowers` (no extension) will result in Apache searching for an appropriate file to return (based on mime-type) by trying various file extensions of files found in that directory. This is achieved with an *internal subrequest* before mod_rewrite runs.

However, it's not clear why this would be a problem in your case if you have no other directives? Since your directive simply rewrites *everything* to `test.html` (which should include any subrequests). (I was unable to reproduce this behaviour on my Apache 2.4 test server - hence my initial doubt.)

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-1-%E2%80%94-enabling-mod_rewrite) DigitalOcean article on rewriting URLs said to add `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` to my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file. Removing the MultiViews option solved the issue as well.

Comment: You need `FollowSymLinks` for mod_rewrite to work, however, you probably don't want `Indexes` (allows Apache mod_autoindex to generate directory listings when navigating to a directory without a directory index document - a potential security issue) or `MultiViews`. As you have found, `MultiViews` is more likely to cause conflicts if you are using mod_rewrite.